# Función en PDO para escapar caracteres especiales

Tags: php, pdo

¿Cuál es la función que actualmente se está utilizando en **`PDO`** para escapar caracteres especiales antes de realizar una sentencia SQL?

Antes de empezar a utilizar **`PDO`** estaba utilizando `real_escape_string()`, además de otras que sirven para limpiar *strings* como `strip_tags()`, `htmlespecialchars()` entre otras.

No sé si `real_escape_string` se pueda seguir utilizando en **`PDO`** o solo quedo para el driver de `mysqli`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el método `prepare`, lo puedes hacer del siguiente modo:

```php
$sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE id  = ? ");
```

Y usando el signo de interrogación, que será dinámico, pues, recibirá el valor por el cual se hará la consulta.

O puedes probar con el método `bindParam();`

```php
$id = 1;
$sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM publicaciones WHERE id = :id");
$sentencia->bindParam(':id', $id);
$sentencia->execute();
```

`bindParam();` vincula el valor a una variable en específico.

Comment: Bien @Alfredo Paz, de hecho de esa manera realizo mis consultas, lo que no sabia era que esos metodos realizan esa funcion tambien. Muchas gracias por aclarar!